# how to make watch sign using xamarin for add the video to watch later list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a video streaming app view series and movies and I have faced a problem.

the problem is that I can't make listview contains episode number and eye icon that when I press on it this episode will be added to the watch later list and the eye icon will be changed after this to an orange eye icon.

Now the problem:
when I made a custom viewcell I couldn't give the label in it a value so the icon is the only thing that will be shown because I don't know how to pass a binding value for the label.
here is my XAML code for viewcell

```
 public EpisodeViewCell()
    {
        Label episodenum = new Label();
        Image eyebtn = new Image();
        eyebtn.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Kitsune_Zone.imgs.emptyeye.png");
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout { Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0), FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft, Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, Children = { episodenum, eyebtn } };

        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions = {
                                new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
                             },
            ColumnDefinitions = {
                                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
                                }
        };
        grid.Children.Add(stackLayout, 0, 0);


        Frame frame = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.FromHex("6fbeff"),
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("0C0C0C"),
            CornerRadius = 30,
            HeightRequest = 20,
            Margin = new Thickness(35, 5, 35, 0),
            Content = grid
        };
        View = frame;
        //bindings
        eyebtn.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;

    }
```

and here is how I implement it

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Episode}" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" x:Name="lstseries" HasUnevenRows="True" Margin="20" >
                        <ListView.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:DeselectItemBehavior />
                            <behaviors1:ListViewHeightBehavior ExtraSpace="180"/>
                        </ListView.Behaviors>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <episodesection:EpisodeViewCell x:Name="par"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

can anyone tell me how to pass a value for the label that is in viewcell to be shown with the eye icon
or can anyone suggest another solution for a thing like this.

example :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the icon of button in runtime , you could define a bindable property to change the value .

#### in your custom cell

```
public partial class EpisodeViewCell : ViewCell
{ 
    public EpisodeViewCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //...
        //binding 
       

    }



    public static readonly BindableProperty IsWatchLaterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsWatchLater", typeof(bool), typeof(EpisodeViewCell), false,propertyChanged: OnChanged);


    static void OnChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var isNext = (bool)newValue;
        var cell = bindable as EpisodeViewCell;
        if(isNext)
        {
            cell.eyebtn.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("xxx.png");
        }
        else
        {
            cell.eyebtn.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("xxx.png");
        }

    }

    public bool IsWatchLater
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsWatchLaterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsWatchLaterProperty, value); }
    }



}
```

#### in Model

Add a new property

```
public class YourModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public bool isWatchLater;
    public bool IsWatchLater
    {
        get { return isWatchLater; }
        set
        {
            isWatchLater = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsWatchLater");
        }
    }


    //...other properties

}
```

#### in xaml

Binding the property to model ,or you could binding it in code behind

```
<episodesection:EpisodeViewCell IsWatchLater = "{Binding IsWatchLater}"  x:Name="par"/>
```

Now you could change the value of **IsWatchLater** in ViewModel to control the icon of the button .

Comment: thank you very much for your replay.. now I have 1 thing too how can I display episode number beside the eyebtn. i mean I want to make a list that includes episodes number and every item in the list has the episode number and beside the episode number the eye button. and my database is controlled by web API .

Comment: Set the text of button , binding it to the id of model .

Comment: i can't understand you how can i bind it to the id model ? while I'm making this <episodesection:EpisodeViewCell IsWatchLater = "{Binding IsWatchLater}"  x:Name="par"/>

Comment: eyebtn.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty,"xxx");  // xx here is the id or some peoperty like index in your model . You could add a property on model like the above code .'

Comment: You mean that i can replace xxx by the model item ?    I have episode that is the itemsource for the listview so i can replace xxx to episodenum where episodenum is a part of episode inside my model?

Comment: i have tried 
episodenum.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,"EpisodeNum"); 
and there is no changes happened and I got error also in this line 
cell.eyebtn.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("xxx.png");  
 error:
 CS1061 C# does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: so the 2 problems still exist and I didn't get the solution

Comment: can u help please?

Comment: i want to make like that look at this image [link](https://ibb.co/4YzyDdh)

Comment: help me please brother.

Comment: The problem now is the words in the list isn't displayed ... The image is the only thing displayed in this list so how to make it like the image in the previous comment?

Comment: Could you share your sample with static data ?

Comment: i already shared my example with static data in the comments and here is the image again [Example Image](https://ibb.co/4YzyDdh)

Comment: I didn't see any sample link .

Comment: Look at the image that is included in the post